# Concatenação em Ruby e .object_id

Tags: string, ruby

Olá, amigos!

Estava estudando Ruby e ao ler os métodos de concatenação notei uma pequena diferença. Quando testei o primeiro método através do "+", notei que ao usar o `.object_id` ele me gera um id antes, e após a concatenação ele me passa um id diferente.

**Usando o método "+":**

```
x = "Método de"
puts x.object_id
x = x + "concatenação"
puts x
puts x.object_id
```

**Resultado no terminal:**

```
47068325481320
Método de concatenação
47068325481120
```

Já usando o `shovel (<<)`, notei que ele faz a concatenação da mesma maneira, porém ele retorna o mesmo object_id:

**Usando o método "<<":**

```
x = "Método de "
puts x.object_id
x << "concatenação"
puts x
puts x.object_id
```

**Resultado no terminal:**

```
47453902360060
Método de concatenação
47453902360060
```

Gostaria de saber o porquê ao usar o "+" para concatenar strings ele me gera um novo objeto, sendo que em ambos os casos antes e após a concatenação continua sendo a mesma variável 'x'.

Qual a influência disso no meu sistema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você mesmo descobriu:

> O método `+=` gera e faz a variável apontar para uma nova `String`:

```
# exemplo mostra id mudando para uma mesma variável
irb(main):010:0> minha_var = "hello"
irb(main):011:0> minha_var.object_id # => 17187071060
irb(main):012:0> minha_var += " world"
irb(main):013:0> minha_var.object_id # => 17187027180
```

> O método `<<` altera o próprio objeto:

```
# exemplo mostra id permanecendo inalterado
irb(main):014:0> outra_var = "foo"
irb(main):015:0> outra_var.object_id # => 17186991840
irb(main):016:0> outra_var << "bar"
irb(main):017:0> outra_var.object_id # => 17186991840
```

## E que diferença isso faz?

Na minha opinião, a diferença que pode trazer problemas práticos e introduzir bugs, é a de que se for feita uma atribuição e em seguida se utilizar o método `<<` para alterar o valor de uma variável, a variável que recebeu o valor anteriormente será também alterada, porque as duas compartilham a mesma referência para o objeto.

#### Usando concat:

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = "foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):002:0> bar = foo
=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> foo << "bar"
=> "foobar"
irb(main):004:0> bar
=> "foobar"
# bar foi alterado quando alteramos foo

irb(main):005:0> foo.object_id == bar.object_id
=> true
```

#### Usando +=:

```
irb(main):006:0> foo = "foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):007:0> bar = foo
=> "foo"
irb(main):008:0> foo += "bar"
=> "foobar"
irb(main):009:0> bar
=> "foo"
# += gerando uma cópia, bar mantém seu valor original

irb(main):010:0> foo.object_id == bar.object_id
=> false
```

## Diferença de performance

Usando o módulo `benchmark`, podemos ver claramente a diferença que faz alterar um objeto ou criar e alocar memória para um novo:

```
require "benchmark"

n = 100000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("<<") do
    foo = "foo"
    n.times do
      foo << "bar"
    end
  end

  x.report("+=") do
    foo = "foo"
    n.times do
      foo += "bar"
    end
  end
end
```

Resultado:

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------
<<   0.023438   0.007812   0.031250 (  0.019828)
+=   4.992188   2.570312   7.562500 (  7.740998)
----------------------------- total: 7.593750sec

         user     system      total        real
<<   0.015625   0.000000   0.015625 (  0.018702)
+=   5.007812   1.132812   6.140625 (  6.176764)
```

---

Material vergonhosamente tirado das seguintes páginas:
[Why is the shovel operator (<<) preferred over plus-equals (+=) when building a string in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684446/why-is-the-shovel-operator-preferred-over-plus-equals-when-building-a)
[A Little More About Strings](http://library.edgecase.com/a-little-more-about-strings)

Outra página interessante sobre performance e Strings:
[Never create Ruby strings longer than 23 characters](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/4/never-create-ruby-strings-longer-than-23-characters)

Answer (score 3):

Adicionando às outras respostas: Quando você usa `<<`, pelo fato de estar alterando o próprio objeto, pode ser que você altere uma string passada para uma função de dentro dela e isso tenha efeitos fora.

Por exemplo:

```
def muda_string(string)
  string << "bar"
  # Faz alguma coisa com a string aqui...
end

a = "foo"
muda_string(a)

puts a # => foobar
```

Pode parecer óbvio, mas isso acaba passando despercebido às vezes e pode causar alguns efeitos colaterais bem difíceis de depurar.

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro caso você está retribuindo um valor para a variável "x", por isso gera um id diferente. No caso vc esta criando novamente a variable "x"

No segundo caso, você está adicionando o valor para dentro da variável existente.

Comment: Então o método "<<" seria o mais eficiente em termos de memória/velocidade?